# react: ReactGridLayout.children[0].x must be a number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The issue is not similar to the one with the same title.

I am using react hook to create my own dynamic add/remove using this [example](https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout/blob/master/test/examples/6-dynamic-add-remove.jsx) to create my dynamic add/remove.

As the title suggests, the error message happens when clicking the 'create item' button.

This is my codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-grid-layout-with-resizable-forked-zw7qy?file=/src/index.js) that shows my code and the error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you were having is that your `widget` state is set as an array of objects but when you were updating that state in the `onAddItem` function you were setting the it as an object.

Here's the `onAddItem` function where the `widget` state is being updated with the previous state and the new state into a new array.

```
const onAddItem = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
    setWidgetList([
      ...widget,
      {
        i: "chart" + counter,
        x: (widget.length * 2) % (cols || 12),
        y: Infinity, // puts it at the bottom
        w: 2,
        h: 2
      }
    ]);
  };
```